# Working with yacc and lex

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, bison, yacc, lex

I have this simple example that I want to play with: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78627401/calculator.tar.gz

This interactive calculator let's you evaluate arithmetic expressions involving integer literals and variables.

I want to give it some inputs and see how it works. I'm trying to follow http://epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/download/LexAndYaccTutorial.pdf but I get lost.

Can you explain how to setup the environment and start playing with the example, in Ubuntu 14 ?

To be **specific**,

- what commands should i use to setup the environment?
- what are the commands I should use on lex, yacc and c++ files to get ready to test?
- with what commands i can give file inputs to the parser via CLI?
- how to see the output of the parser?

Comment: have you ever compiled a C (or C++) program?

Comment: Sorry, that might have sounded rude. But it's a real question: I don't know how much of the build process you need explained. If you have never compiled a multi-file C project, it is definitely more complicated to explain what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have already installed gcc, you just need

```
sudo apt-get install flex bison
```